# how to fix Session app: 'Error while Launching activity' in android studio 3.2.1

Tags: android-studio, android-activity, launching

I useing genymotion samsung s6 api21 and my app isn't launched.

this is my error:

```
Split APKs installed in 15 s 824 ms
$ adb shell am start -n
"com.simplemobiletools.calculator.debug/com.simplemobiletools.calculator.activities.SplashActivity.Orange" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Error while executing: am start -n "com.simplemobiletools.calculator.debug/com.simplemobiletools.calculator.activities.SplashActivity.Orange" -a android.intent.action.MAIN -c android.intent.category.LAUNCHER
Starting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.MAIN cat=[android.intent.category.LAUNCHER] cmp=com.simplemobiletools.calculator.debug/com.simplemobiletools.calculator.activities.SplashActivity.Orange }
Error type 3
Error: Activity class {com.simplemobiletools.calculator.debug/com.simplemobiletools.calculator.activities.SplashActivity.Orange} does not exist.

Error while Launching activity
```

I tried these:

- clean project, rebuild project, and run again
- Disabled Instant Run and tried.
- Invalid caches/ Restart.. option tried.
- all SDK and tools were update

I read most of related questions.I don't know what to do ?